# Process '/usr/share/usbmount/usbmount add' failed with exit code 32 (automounting sd cards)

Tags: mount, 22.04, automount, sd-card

After updating to Ubuntu 22.04.2, usbmount no longer works. `/var/logs/syslog` contains the following:

```
May 21 13:57:44 homeserver usbmount[8979]: loaded usbmount configurations
May 21 13:57:44 homeserver usbmount[8979]: trying to acquire lock /var/run/usbmount/.mount.lock
May 21 13:57:44 homeserver usbmount[8979]: acquired lock /var/run/usbmount/.mount.lock
May 21 13:57:44 homeserver usbmount[8979]: /dev/sdc1 contains filesystem type exfat
May 21 13:57:44 homeserver usbmount[8979]: mountpoint /media/usb0 is available for /dev/sdc1
May 21 13:57:44 homeserver usbmount[8979]: executing command: mount -texfat -osync,noexec,nodev,noatime,nodiratime /dev/sdc1 /media/usb0
May 21 13:57:44 homeserver systemd-udevd[8932]: sdc1: Process '/usr/share/usbmount/usbmount add' failed with exit code 32.
```

Running `sudo mount -texfat -osync,noexec,nodev,noatime,nodiratime /dev/sdc1 /media/usb0` manually works fine.

I have tried allowing udevd more access, the following `/etc/systemd/system/systemd-udevd.service.d/00-override.conf` content:

```
[Service]
PrivateMounts=no
MountFlags=shared
```

But to no avail. What am I missing?

`lsblk -f` content for good measure:

```
NAME        FSTYPE   FSVER LABEL    UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
...
sdc                                                                                     
└─sdc1      exfat    1.0   sdreader
```